# Declaring an object when type is "unknown"

Tags: c#, object

Here is my problem:

I have the function

```
public static void fillObject(object [] obs, DataTable dt)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.Rows[j];
        fillObject(obs[j], dr);
    }
}
```

`obs` is an array of some type of class (let say for the example "sheep") when I debug I get that `obs[j]` is a `null` and not an object type of `sheep` so I need to do something like

```
obs[j] = new sheep();
```

any ideas?

Comment: how do you know what type you need to use to create obs[j]?

Comment: `obs[j] = new sheep();` should do what you're describing. Unless you mean that `obs` itself is null. In which case you need to say `obs = new object[100];`

Comment: Paste your error message, and highlight the line of code where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: Honestly, this code doesn't even make sense unless you can guarantee that `dt.Rows[j]` is always a datatable.  The name `fillObject` implies you're trying to populate something, but it's unclear to me what.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to strongly type your solution, you can use generics

```
public static void FillObject<T>(T [] obs, DataTable dt) where T: new
{
    //...

    obs[j] = new T();
}
```

You would then call the function like

```
FillObject<Sheep>(mySheep, dt);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm tnx a lot! just need to put after the new "()"

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean; depending on the specific scenario, you could do one of the following:

You can pass a construction function to the method:

```
public static void fillObject(object [] obs, DataTable dt, Func<object> builder)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
   {
      DataRow dr = dt.Rows[j];

      if (obs[j] == null)
         obs[j] = builder();

      fillObject(obs[j], dr);
   }
}
```

Or if you know the type, you can use a dictionary of construction functions:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> sBuilders = new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>
{
   { typeof(Type1), () => new Type1() },
   { typeof(Type2), () => new Type2() },
   // etc...
};

public static void fillObject(object [] obs, DataTable dt, Type pType)
{
   for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
   {
      DataRow dr = dt.Rows[j];

      if (obs[j] == null)
         obs[j] = sBuilders[pType]();

      fillObject(obs[j], dr);
   }
}
```